# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function - other answers haven't helped me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module, export

I'm an idiot and can't figure this out. I've googled this question on SOF a bunch of times but I can't seem to resolve the issue, so I'm asking directly for myself. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's my Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.js'

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Navbar from "./Navbar.js"
import HoldBar from "./Holdbar.js"
import ChoiceBar from "./ChoiceBar.js"
import Footer from "./Footer.js"

function App() {
  return (
    <div class="App">
      <Navbar />
      <HoldBar />
      <ChoiceBar />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need to narrow it down. Render them one by one until you find the one responsible for the error. Then post that one's code here

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to directly tell you where the issue is, but I can explain where to look. The error above occurs when you try to use something within JSX that isn't a valid component.

e.g.

```
var X = 42;
<X />; // this would create the same error
```

So this is what I would do:

Start by making a component that uses `componentDidCatch` and start wrapping your custom components to find the place where you are trying to render an invalid React component.

Comment: Thank you, I tried rendering them one by one and deduced the problem. Thank you so much!